# Is it possible to break the rule: If the super class method declares an exception then subclass overridden method cannot declare parent exception?

Tags: java, exception, overriding

So when we were talking about java exceptions rules I completely understand the rule:

> If the superclass method declares an exception then subclass overridden method cannot declare parent exception(for checked exceptions)

But I have the following issue:

```
    public class BaseException extends Exception
{

    public BaseException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}

public class ClassExtendsExceptionChildOne extends BaseException
{

    public ClassExtendsExceptionChildOne(String s)
    {
       super(s);
    }
}
```

I have to use the described above custom exceptions to achieve the following results in these two classes:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{    
    public abstract void abstractMethod2() throws ClassExtendsExceptionChildOne;   
}

public class ChildClassOne extends MyClass
{
    @Override
    public void abstractMethod2() throws BaseException{}
}
```

I understand that I break one of exceptions override rules, but is there a possibility to achieve this my intention or I have worked totally wrong?

Comment: with checked exception you can only be more specific i.e. throw that class or a sub-classes.

Comment: What happens when someone writes `MyClass = new ChildClassOne();` then runs `abstractMethod2`? The compiler doesn't know it's actually `ChildClassOne`. It only knows it's a `MyClass`. How will you be able to write a `try-catch` or a `throws` for `BaseException` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a possibility to achieve this my intention

It is possible but this is a hack and likely to cause confusion. I strongly suggest you avoid it this as a design principle.

> or I have worked totally wrong?

Once you have decided which checked exceptions the method in the super class can throw, the sub-class should honour this and not throw a different checked exception or anyone calling the sub-class method is in for a shock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will take it into attention. And one more, you said: It is possible but this is a hack and likely to cause confusion. Just for information how to achieve it?